# Incorrect y coordinate of text matrix (tm) using pypdf 3.7.0

Tags: pypdf, transformation-matrix

I'm using pypdf 3.7.0 to extract text from a pdf file. I need the text's location to do subsequent operations, so I extract the text along with its x and y coordinates from the text matrix. However, while there is no issue with the x coordinate, the y coordinates are incorrect.

I tried to check the page size to make sure that the file wasn't scaled, which is correct (the page size is 612x792).

I think one of the ways to solve this issue is to do some modification with the transformation matrix (cm) with the text matrix (tm), but I haven't figured out how to do that.

Note: A reason why I think about the transformation matrix (cm) is that for other pdf files, its value is [1,0,0,1,0,0] (Identity matrix if you put it in 3x3). However, for this pdffile, the values of cm keep on changing (especially the last 2 elements in the matrix).

Link to the pdf file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10KMQVAJPB2hQSOOT6OrnF0RGg82k6i31/view?usp=sharing

Below is an code example of the first page.(The issue happens with all the pages)

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

def visitor_body(text, cm, tm, fontDict, fontSize):
  x, y = tm[4], tm[5]
  print('This is text',text)
  print('This is tm',tm)
  print('This is cm',cm)

py_reader = PdfReader("Typhoon Merbok PVRR.pdf")
py_page = py_reader.pages[0]

print('This is page size',py_page.mediabox)
py_page.extract_text(visitor_text=visitor_body)
```

This is the result:

```
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 699.75]
This is text Typhoon Merbok
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 138.5182341, 17.92000058]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 699.75]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 138.5182341, 17.92000058]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 683.25]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 683.25]
This is text 17 September, 2022
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 127.91241470000003, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 683.25]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 127.91241470000003, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 669.75]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 669.75]
This is text Released:
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 64.36441049999999, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 669.75]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 669.75]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 73.317032, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 669.75]
This is text 31 October, 2022
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 177.6134188, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 669.75]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 177.6134188, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 656.25]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 656.25]
This is text NHERI DesignSafe Project ID:
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 201.9814454, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 656.25]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 201.9814454, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 642.75]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 15.3599997]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 642.75]
This is text PRJ-
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 27.6880035, 15.3599997]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 642.75]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 642.75]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 36.640625, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 642.75]
This is text 3737
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 36.640625, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 642.75]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 36.640625, 15.35999966]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 76.5, 615.75]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 31.672241, 1.02156258]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 76.5, 615.75]
This is text PRELIMINARY VIRTUAL RECONNAISSANCE REPORT (PVRR)
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 573.4407955, 17.92000058]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 76.5, 615.75]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 573.4407955, 17.92000058]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 522.0]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 95.317818, 1.02156258]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 522.0]
This is text Virtual Assessment Structural Team (VAST) Lead
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 516.5935141, 17.92000058]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 522.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 516.5935141, 17.92000058]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 505.5]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 155.507813, 15.89333344]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 505.5]
This is text Mohammad Alam, University of Notre Dame
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 243.546876, 15.89333344]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 505.5]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 243.546876, 15.89333344]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 480.0]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 81.33474, 1.02156258]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 480.0]
This is text Virtual Assessment Structural Team (VAST) Authors
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 530.9040763, 17.92000058]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 480.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 530.9040763, 17.92000058]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 463.5]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 234.625, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 463.5]
This is text (in alphabetical order)
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 234.625, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 463.5]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 234.625, 15.35999966]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 449.25]
This is text  

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 160.804688, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 449.25]
This is text Janise Rodgers, GeoHazards International
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 160.804688, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 449.25]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 160.804688, 15.35999966]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 435.0]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 186.91797, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 435.0]
This is text Prateek Arora, New York University
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 339.003908, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 435.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 339.003908, 15.35999966]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 420.75]
This is text  

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 182.59766, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 420.75]
This is text Stephanie Pilkington, UNC Charlotte
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 182.59766, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 420.75]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 182.59766, 15.35999966]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 396.0]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 251.35808, 1.02156258]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 396.0]
This is text PVRR Editors
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 362.2662068, 17.92000058]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 396.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 362.2662068, 17.92000058]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 379.5]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 241.12329, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 379.5]
This is text (in alphabetical order)
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 377.9960624999998, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 379.5]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 377.9960624999998, 14.079999970000001]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 366.0]
This is text  

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 187.05859, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 366.0]
This is text Ian Robertson, University of Hawaii
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 187.05859, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 366.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 187.05859, 15.35999966]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 351.75]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 197.00391, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 351.75]
This is text Kurt Gurley , University of Florida
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 276.73047299999996, 15.35999966]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 78.75, 351.75]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 276.73047299999996, 15.35999966]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 72.0, 71.25]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 232.0, 0.65671921]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 72.0, 71.25]
This is text PVRR: 17 September , 2022 T yphoon Merbok
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 393.847657, 11.520000510000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 72.0, 71.25]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 393.847657, 11.520000510000001]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 72.0, 60.75]
This is text  

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 232.0, 11.520000510000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 72.0, 60.75]
This is text PRJ-3737 | Released: 31 October , 2022
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 411.22069999999997, 11.520000510000001]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 72.0, 60.75]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 411.22069999999997, 11.520000510000001]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 72.0, 50.25]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 232.0, 15.3599997]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 72.0, 50.25]
This is text Building Resilience through Reconnaissance
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 232.0, 15.3599997]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 72.0, 50.25]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 72.0, 50.25]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 576.0, 15.3599997]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 72.0, 50.25]
This is text 1
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 576.0, 15.3599997]
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 72.0, 50.25]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 576.0, 15.3599997]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 576.0, 15.3599997]
This is cm [290.39792, 0.0, 0.0, 66.75, 67.78627, 631.5]
This is text 

This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 576.0, 15.3599997]
This is cm [290.39792, 0.0, 0.0, 66.75, 67.78627, 631.5]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 576.0, 15.3599997]
This is cm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 792.0]
This is text 
This is tm [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 576.0, 15.3599997]
This is cm [157.5, 0.0, 0.0, 36.0, 79.5, 36.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unclear why you think the cm values are not correct ? so lets pick the first letter of your minimal sample `T y p h o o n`

```
This is cm [0.75, 0.0, 0.0, -0.75, 363.75, 699.75]
This is text Typhoon Merbok
```

Lets see where it is placed as its rounded values in my gui editor we need to compare using a small leeway. as you say 363.75 x is here shown rounded to 363.8

[image]

You will need to enlarge image to see other vector as (92.3) =92.25 from top, However that not the way PDF uses co-ords it calculates in a chartlike cartesian co-ordinate system (Origin Lower Left)

So to compare with the PDF we need to subtract that from the previously defined 792.0 thus the T is at 792.0-92.25 = 699.75 and we can see that's the cm location as given by `363.75, 699.75]`

Likewise the top of 17 September is 108.75 from top of page = 683.25 in Y `363.75, 683.25]`

As we move down the "Page" the Y value will naturally decrease.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. About my question, I'm having problems with the y coordinates obtained from the text matrix (tm) not the transformation matrix (cm). I use text matrix instead of transformation matrix (cm) because it is suggested in pypdf tutorial when dealing with text location. I mention the transformation matrix because I think if I can change the transformation matrix to an identity matrix, I can use the text matrix like in other pdf files. Link to pypdf suggestion: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you have any suggestions when dealing with text location? Because for other pdf files, the text matrix works fine, and most of the transformation matrices are identity (even if the transformation matrices are not identity, the text matrix coordinates are still ok).